# Where do you put native libraries for a web app (in Caucho Resin)?

Tags: java, web-applications, resin, java.library.path, java-native-library

Where do native libraries for a web app go so that that Resin will load them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM will load libraries from the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

RESIN_HOME/libexec or RESIN_HOME/libexec64 (depending on OS) will be added to Resin's environment automatically.

Checking what's being set for these can be done with passing --verbose flag to bin/resinctl.